# Why does my pyinstaller executable file not working

Tags: python, windows, pyinstaller

I made a really simple script just as a joke and i want to make it into a .exe file so I tried to use pyinstaller but whenever I try to open the .exe file it just opens and closes. I tried adding a sleep but it didn't work.

here is my code

```
import time
name = input('what is your name?\n')

print('fck you', name)

time.sleep(1)

import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
print(s.getsockname()[0])
s.close()
```

here is the .spec also do I need to download something for the .spec it just shows up as a generic file

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-


block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(
    ['open.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
    win_private_assemblies=False,
    cipher=block_cipher,
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data, cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.zipfiles,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='open',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
```

I tried to open it through cmd it gives me this

```
C:\Users\------\Desktop>open.exe
[8072] Module object for pyimod02_importers is NULL!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod02_importers.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "pathlib.py", line 14, in <module>
  File "urllib\parse.py", line 40, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ipaddress'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyiboot01_bootstrap.py", line 17, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyimod02_importers'
[8072] Failed to execute script 'pyiboot01_bootstrap' due to unhandled exception!
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include any relevant code. See here for how to create a [mre].

Comment: ok there sorry I am very new

Comment: `input()` isn't intended for use in GUI applications. It's really only useful in console (CLI) apps. So I'm not sure how `name = input('what is your name?\n')` is going to behave in an executable.

Comment: I have tried to make exe files with python scripts that don't have a input and it hasn't worked it just opens the console and closes it immediately

Comment: @JRiggles pyinstaller uses a cut down interpreter so the input would not be an issue

Answer (score 1):

FIXED
it was an incompatible version of python with pyinstaller i used 3.7.8

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).